# Replace content of div through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a file `login.ejs` which start with `<div id="loginPage">` and then contains a login form. I then have a file `index.ejs` `with a <div id="container">` id. I want to be able to click a link outside of the container-div which would replace the content of the container-div with the content of the loginPage div. In my `index.ejs` I have:

```
<a href="#" id='admin' title="admin"><p><b>Admin</b></p></a>
```

and I have a script in `index.js`:

```
function events() {
    // register events
        $('#admin').click(function()
        {
            $('#container').html('#loginPage');
            return false;
        });
}
```

But I cannot get it to work, anyone that could give some ideas please?

Comment: `$('#container').html($('#loginPage').html());`

Comment: You mentioned that the two `<div>` elements are in **different** files; do they both exist on the page at the same time when you click the `#admin` link? If not, you're going to have to load the content with AJAX.

Comment: No, sorry it did not. I am trying to look into it more deeply atm.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do like as below , first get html like `$('#loginPage').html()` and than assign this html to container .

```
$('#admin').click(function()
        {
            $('#container').html($('#loginPage').html());
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

to be precise use the `load` function:

```
$('#admin').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#container').load('login.ejs #loginPage');
});//--------------------^^^^^^^^--^^^^^^^^^^-----loads the <div id="loginPage">
   //---------------------------------------------from the login.ejs
```